# Lines to JPanel not working

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, line

My main method is set up like so:

```
JPanel contentPane;
    contentPane = (JPanel) rootPaneContainer.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setSize(508, 650);
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(contentPane.getX(), contentPane.getY(), 508, 470);
    panel.setBackground(new Color(177, 154, 212));
    panel.add(new LinePaintDemo());   
    contentPane.add(panel);
    contentPane.setVisible(true);
```

And my LinePaintDemo class is set up like so:

```
public class LinePaintDemo extends JPanel{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      try
      {
        scan = new Scanner(new File("area.map"));
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      StringTokenizer token;

        double prevx = 0;
        double prevy = 0;
        double nextx = 0;
        double nexty = 0;

      while(scan.hasNextLine())
      {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        token = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
        if(token.nextToken().equals("4"))
        {
          prevx = Double.parseDouble(token.nextToken());
          prevy = Double.parseDouble(token.nextToken());
        }
        else
        {
          nextx = Double.parseDouble(token.nextToken());
          nexty = Double.parseDouble(token.nextToken());    
        }

        g.drawLine((int)prevx, (int)prevy, (int)nextx, (int)nexty);
        prevx = nextx;
        prevy = nexty;
      }
```

area.map contains points in which to draw lines from. A 4 means move to, a 5 means draw from. Something like so,

4,139.0,172.0

5,135.0,175.0

5,131.0,176.0

5,125.0,190.0

However, when it's being painted, it just shows a small box in my JPanel, like so:

[image: The Program]

Any suggestions as to why it's doing this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `panel.setBounds(contentPane.getX(), contentPane.getY(), 508, 470);` is not a good idea for a number of reasons, to start with, the `contentPane` has a layout manager, the coordinate system is also based on the parent, meaning that the top left corner is `0x0`, it's already offset for you

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay so if I get rid of setBounds, how does panel get represented in contentPane? Removing setBounds just gets rid of the colored JPanel

Comment: By default `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout`, but `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout`.

Comment: I think you might want to have a look at [Laying out components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay, so I understand the types of layouts that are used by each one by default. BorderLayout which can be used like BorderLayout.CENTER. I could set the panel layout to null, but obviously setting it to null won't call paintComponent, which doesn't do what I need. Why does a default layout manager effect how paint is called?

Comment: @SwaggyC The layout manager can affect the `paintComponent` because if the components size is `0x0`, what's the point of painting.  The `FlowLayout` is provide some padding, which is why it's a nice little square. You component doesn't have any concept of size, so it's been default to `0x0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your custom panel needs to implement the `getPreferredSize()` method so layout manager can do their job.
2. A painting method is for painting only. You should NOT  be using a Scanner to get input. The Scanner logic should be invoked from the constructor of your class. You will then have two approaches to do your painting a) you can store object you want to paint or b) you can paint to a BufferedImage. Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for examples of both of these approaches.